# How would I compile this java project directory that was made in Eclipse in mac terminal?

Tags: java, compilation, terminal, directory, src

I have this directory:

```
JavaProject (root folder)
    /audio
    /bin
        /keys
        /ScreenManagement
    /images
    /src
        /keys
        /ScreenManagement
```

The bin folder has all the class files.
The src folder has all the java files.

The main file that needs to be run is Game which is a java file in the src, and a class file in the bin. I am currently running it by using this command in the terminal:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII -classpath "/Users/chris/Documents/School/-Senior/CSC 225 A/JavaProject/bin" Game
```

What command would I need to use to compile the files into the proper directories when I make a change to a java file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `javac -d /Users/chris/Documents/School/-Senior/CSC 225 A/JavaProject/bin sourcefile_you_want_to_compile` inside the src directory.

Or are you asking for the source to be compiled automatically after changes are made?